# Adding a variable inside codeigniter activerecord subquery

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Im trying to create an active query where there is a variable inside a subquery

```
$fb_UID = $this->session->userdata('fb_UID');

$qs = $this->db->select("*,qs.UID as qs_UID")->
from("question_set qs")->
join("questions q","qs.UID=q.fk_question_set_UID","inner")->
where("sickness_UID",$id)->
where('`qs.UID` NOT IN(SELECT `fk_question_set_UID` FROM `solved_qset` where fk_fb_UID = `$fb_UID`)', NULL, FALSE)->
group_by("qs.UID","asc")->
order_by("qs.UID","random")->
get()->row();
```

but i get an error

```
Unknown column '$fb_UID' in 'where clause'
```

is there a way to properly place a variable inside an active record sub query?

thanks

Comment: Not being familiar with codeigniter, I have to assume there's a better way to do that with a bound parameter, but your immediate problem is that you're doing it inside a single-quoted string, which does not interpolate the variable in PHP. It needs to be double-quoted.

Comment: and it looks like all your other PHP strings are double-quoted. Only that one was single-quoted.

Comment: thanks finally got it working by changing the single quote of my subquery to double quotes; removing the ticks enclosing the variable in single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think you cannot combine many single quotes. If you use single quotes outside you should use double quotes inside of this single quotes, and it's the same when double quotes are outside.

```
where('"qs.UID" NOT IN(SELECT "fk_question_set_UID" 
FROM "solved_qset" where fk_fb_UID = "$fb_UID")', NULL, FALSE)->// try this....
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, and concatenate the variable:

```
$fb_UID = $this->session->userdata('fb_UID');    
$qs = $this->db
     ->select("*,qs.UID as qs_UID")
     ->from("question_set qs")
     ->join("questions q","qs.UID=q.fk_question_set_UID","inner")
     ->where("sickness_UID",$id)
     ->where('`qs.UID` NOT IN(SELECT `fk_question_set_UID`
               FROM `solved_qset` where fk_fb_UID = '.$fb_UID.')', NULL, FALSE)
     ->group_by("qs.UID","asc")
     ->order_by("qs.UID","random")
     ->get()->row();
```